# How to make HTTP calls, using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to **practise making HTTP calls** (...if that is what it's called) from a simple ASP.NET MVC web application. To do this, I am attempting to get weather details from [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/appid). You can do this by:

> - Add the following parameter to the GET request: APPID=APIKEY
>
>   - Example: *api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=1111111111*

**My understanding,** from my learning:

- The *controller* is the one to make the above HTTP call.

**My question:**

- How do I actually make that HTTP GET request, in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: EDIT: I understand that there are many ways, so what is a 'simple, easy' way, to get started?

Comment: If you mean that you want to make HTTP calls from within your code, invoked by your server-side application, then note that this really doesn't have anything to do with MVC.  Any .NET code would use objects like `HttpClient` to make HTTP requests and receive responses.  MVC is the front-end application host for your code, but you're talking about back-end .NET code which can be invoked from any application host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

You can do some basic reading from a website using something like the following:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    string textResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

You may want to make sure to test `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` (checks for an HTTP 200 result) to make sure the result is what you expect before you parse it.

Comment: Cheers. 
The main 'beef' for me were these lines:
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content);

Comment: *CS4033: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing it's return type to 'Task'."*

So, what does the method declaration surrounding this code look like, and what is the valid ```Task<T>``` value you use in the corresponding ```return``` statement? 

Comment: Also, ```client.GetAsync(uri)``` returns a value of type ```Task<HttpResponseMessage>```, which has neither the ```Content``` nor ```IsSuccessStatusCode``` fields. Under VS2022/.Net-7.0, this 'answer' is literally not even valid code, let alone a 'solution'.